# Passing value of component to another Scene to use in post method - react native

Tags: react-native

I need Some Help as possible.
In my code I have scene that return into my view, an array with names. However, I want to do something also. When I click the name, I want to take the email of the name I have clicked and past to my post method, to return in another scene with information of the email person. Here is my code:

**My Users Class with all elements**

```
import React from 'react';
import ListaItens from './ListaUsers'
import BarraNavegacao from './BarraNavegacao';
import {View,Image,Alert,TouchableHighlight,AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Users extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {tituloBarraNav: 'Colaboradores',testLocal:''};
}
```

**My refresh function is into Component Users**

```
  async refresh() {
    let tmp_localData = {};
    AsyncStorage.getItem('localData', (err, result) => {
        //console.log(result);
        tmp_localData = JSON.parse(result);
        //console.log('Local temp: ', tmp_localData.User.email);

    }).then((result) => {
        tmp_localData = JSON.parse(result);

        //console.log('Email: ', tmp_localData.email);
        axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'my url'
                data: {
                    email: 'someEmail@test.com,
                }
            },
            console.log('aqui esta o email'),

        ).then((response) => {
            //console.log('Get tmpLocal ----------',tmp_localData);
            //console.log('Get response ----------',response);
            tmp_localData.User = {
                "userID": response.data.response.userID,
                "displayName": response.data.response.displayName,
                "email": response.data.response.email,
                "avatar": response.data.response.avatar,
                "gender": response.data.response.gender,
                "Session": {
                    "token": response.data.response.token,
                },
                "FootID": response.data.response.FootID,
            };
            //this.refresh();
            //console.log('Set tmpLocal',tmp_localData);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify(tmp_localData), () => {

            }).then((result) => {
                this.props.navigator.push({id: 'MenuPrincipal'});
                console.log('Navigator',this.props.navigator);

                //Alert.alert('Clicou Aqui ');

            });

        }).catch((error) => {
            if (error.response) {
                // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
                // that falls out of the range of 2xx
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
                Alert.alert('Não foi possivel mudar o utilizador');
            } else if (error.request) {
                // The request was made but no response was received
                // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
                // http.ClientRequest in node.js
                console.log('erro de ligaçao', error.message);
                Alert.alert('Não foi possivel mudar o utilizador');
                console.log(error.request);
            } else {
                // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                console.log('erro de codigo no then', error.message);
                Alert.alert('Não foi possivel mudar o utilizador');
            }
            console.log(error.config);
            Alert.alert('Não foi possivel mudar o utilizador');
        });
    });
}
```

**My render in Users**

```
render(){
    const {principal, conteudo,imgConteudo1,imgConteudo2, texto,box}= myStyle;
    return(
        <View style={principal}>

            <BarraNavegacao back navigator={this.props.navigator} tituloProp={this.state.tituloBarraNav}/>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this.refresh();}}
                                clearButtonMode={'while-editing'}
                                activeOpacity={1} underlayColor={'white'}>
                <ListaItens/>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
       );
     }
}
```

I have ListaItems Component that will walk through an array and will put inside ScroolView with map method. So the code is:

**My ListaItems Class**

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import Items from './Items';

export default class ListaItens extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {listaItens: [], listaEmail: [] };
}
componentWillMount() {
    //request http
    axios.get('my url')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({listaItens: response.data.response})
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log('Erro ao imprimir os dados')
        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            {this.state.listaItens.map(item =>(<Items key={item.email} item={item}/>))}
        </ScrollView>
       );
    }
}
```

The last component is the component the build what i want to show inside scrollview in *ListaItems*. The component name is Items. the code is:

**My Items Class**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, Alert, View, Image,} from 'react-native';

export default class Items extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {listaEmail: ''};
}
render() {
    const {foto, conteudo, texto, box, test} = estilo;
    return (
        <View>
            <Text/>
            <Text/>
            <View style={conteudo}>
                <Image style={foto} source={{uri: this.props.item.avatar}}/>
                <Text style={texto}>{this.props.item.displayName}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={test}>
                <Text style={texto}>{this.props.item.email}</Text>
            </View>

        </View>
      );
   }
}
```

So, in **Users Class** for *refresh() function* in the post method on this **email: "someEmail@test.com",** I want to be dynamic, when I click the name of a person in **Items Class**, I want to take the the email here on **this.props.item.email** and put in parameter on post method of **Users Class----refresh()----axios()---Data---email:the email i want to past**.

A litle help here, please. I am desperate right now because i have tryied and I did not make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First move the Touchable to the item

```
export default class Items extends Component {
    render() {
        const { foto, conteudo, texto, box, test } = estilo;
        return (
            <View> //I'm not sure if the this.props.item.email is the one you use, just change it if you need.
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this.props.callback(this.props.item.email); }}
                    clearButtonMode={'while-editing'}
                    activeOpacity={1} underlayColor={'white'}>
                    <Text />
                    <Text />
                    <View style={conteudo}>
                        <Image style={foto} source={{ uri: this.props.item.avatar }} />
                        <Text style={texto}>{this.props.item.displayName}</Text>
                        <View style={test}>
                            <Text>{this.props.item.email}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Them change you function to receive the email param.

```
refresh = (email) => {
    let tmp_localData = {};
    AsyncStorage.getItem('localData', (err, result) => {
        tmp_localData = result;
    }).then((result) => {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'my Url',
            data: {
                email: email,
            }
        })
    })
}
```

And them you can pass the function to component via props

```
render() {
    const { principal, conteudo, imgConteudo1, imgConteudo2, texto, box } =
        myStyle;
    return (
        <View style={principal} >
            <BarraNavegacao back navigator={this.props.navigator} tituloProp={this.state.tituloBarraNav} />
            <ListaItens callback={this.refresh} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I will try this

Comment: i get this error: **_this3.props.calback is not a function in _this3.props.calback(this3.props.email),_this3.props.calback is undefined)**

Comment: This is just an example, you miss the ListItem component, you need to pass the ListItem callback to you Item list nested. Like <Item callback={this.props.callback} />

Comment: i try to do this but does not works. my refresh function, mus be in ListaItems component just like i sead before, or in other component just like in the example?

Comment: I  have alter the code. review to see what i have change and please give to me your opinion is important to me. thank you

Comment: Can you provide the full code example? i'ts hard to know how you render the Items inside ListaItems without it

Comment: I have aready done this. i put all the code here. check out again to see where I have alter de code @Alessandro Macanha

Comment: this should work https://gist.github.com/macanhajc/53ba65ff0732e17b6440a8af761562f5

Comment: I try this but does not work. do you have a skype to make this conversation more easy? if you don't explain me something. The ''callback'', bust be with this name in all of my classes or not? because i do the same as you show it and i get this error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined

Comment: callback is just a name, the idea is, you have a function on main component and you need to call it on a nested child, then you pass the function in the props of that component and you can call using the props of that component.

Comment: In order of what you have said I did this: In Users: **<ListaUsers propsSend={this.refresh}/>**

In ListaItems: **<Items key={item.email} item={item} propsSend={this.props.propsSend}/>**

In Items:  **<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this.props.propsSend(this.props.item.email); }}>**

Am I right??

Comment: That's the idea

Comment: I Have done like this. but a get some error: **Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined**

He does reconize when i do the push on **this.props.navigator.push({ id: 'MenuPrincipal' });** line 33 of the code that you have correct me

Comment: Try change the `async refresh()`  function to `refresh = async () => {/*code*/}` and bind it on constructor `this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this);`

Comment: My God.  @Alessandro Macanha you could be my teacher. It works very good. Thank you for your patience a lot